# Default focus in a form or panel does not set inside a Web browser control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb6, webbrowser-control

I am using [defaultfocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx#code-snippet-3) property to set default focus in a form or panel. I am trying to set default focus for textbox and it works properly in a browser.

But when the same page is loaded using web-browser control in VB6 i am facing the problem. The default focus will not set when page loaded using web-browser control(VB6 Microsoft internet controls). I tried using the same for a simple form and it does not work. I tried using .focus in page load and it also not working inside web-browser control.
Then I tried refreshing the page as shown below

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate "url here"
WebBrowser1.Refresh
```

If i use refresh then focus will be set properly. But this will load the page again(it loads form of aspx again). So is there any other better solution which I can do within my ASP website?  or any solution which can do the same?

Comment: Try tweaking `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` in registry -- more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) -- to use the last installed IE version in web browser control.  I can post a sample how to get current IE version and auto-update the key on your application startup if this fixes autofocus problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

I tried various methods of doing this through the WinForm code and it was not very effective.  If you're needing to set the focus to a textbox, you'll probably have better luck using JavaScript.

If the textbox is a ASP.net server control, you can use:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server">


    <asp:TextBox id="FirstBox" runat="server" /><br>
    <asp:TextBox id="SecondBox" runat="server" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var field = '<%= SecondBox.ClientID%>';
        document.getElementById(field).value = field;
        document.getElementById(field).focus();
        document.getElementById(field).select();
    </script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does.  Edited my script above with the working sample.  Can you please expound on what you are experiencing?  
http://i.imgur.com/8QFyAV1.png

Comment: No it only works in browsers like IE and chrome.Does not work in vb6 web browser control.

Comment: If it does not work for *you* then, maybe you're doing something incorrectly.  I posted a working example with a screenshot of it working for *me*.  I went through the trouble of downloading and installing the ISO's for a 11+ year old development tool, creating an example and posting a screenshot for you showing you that it works.  
And IE *is* the browser in the WebBrowser control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234651(v=vs.90).aspx

Since you apparently don't want help, you won't receive it - from me anyway.

Comment: @onskee - don't feel bad. VB6 is so old that many things can go wrong with it.

Comment: @onskee I checked again and it didn't work in VB6 web browser control.where u hav called the javascript? in body onload?

Answer (score 0):

This is a placeholder post.

```
    '--- fix WebControl compatibility
    lIEMajor = C_Lng(At(Split(pvGetFileVersion(CreateInstance(PROGID_FSO), GetSpecialFolder(ucsOdtSystem) & "\ieframe.dll"), "."), 0))
    If lIEMajor > 7 Then
        With InitRegistryAccess(ucsRegNone, "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION")
            If .ReadProperty(GetErrorProcessName(), 0, ucsRvtDword) < lIEMajor * 1000 Then
                .WriteProperty GetErrorProcessName(), lIEMajor * 1000, 0, ucsRvtDword
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

Code above uses lots of helper functions/classes but the idea is clear -- get IE major, if IE7 or above -> multiply major by 1000 and update HKCY_CURRENT_USER's key if needed

Will update extract snippet and include API declares later.